# How to use a js object in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Okay i have some data that is entered  by form and some that is generated by the page 
Here is my js file that gets and pushes the data to the php file

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {    
    $("#message_sender").submit(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var sender_data = {
            avatar: document.getElementById("user_avatar_hidden").textContent,
            username: document.getElementById("user_username_hidden").textContent,
            message: $("#message_sender").serialize()
        };

        alert(sender_data.message);

        $.ajax({
             url: 'Js_returns/message_sent.php',
             type: 'post',
             data: {"data" : JSON.stringify(sender_data)},
             success: function(data) {
                $("#conversation_table").append(data);
             }
        });
    });
});
```

Now, im accesing the avatar and username normaly but i cant access the message part the way i want.

```
$var= json_decode($_POST["data"]);
    echo $var -> avatar;
```

So if i didnt convert the data into an js object i could easily do $_POST['message_title']; 
I have tried $var -> message -> message_title; (which i know makes no sense but what the heck) and it didnt work

PS the form im pushing with serialize consists of message_title and text_editor_area

Comment: When you `json_decode` it, it will become an associative array. You can't treat it as object. Try `echo $var['avatar'];`

Comment: Thats not the issue here...
When i used json_decode it converted it into an object as said on the php.net site
<?php

$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345

?>

I need a way to access the message object

Comment: Ok, if according to the manual shouldn't it be `$var->{'avatar'}; ` rather than `$var -> avatar;`

Answer (score 1):

PHP does NOT recursively decode a data structure. You sent over `data=sometext` structure, where `sometext` happens to be a JSON-endoded structure. When you decode that JSON, php has absolutely **NO** clue that `message` is a further `serialized()`'d data structure. YOU have to handle that yourself:

```
$var = json_decode($_POST['data']);
$unserialized_data = parse_str($var['message']);
```